# Is there any garbage collection in below code?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is there any garbage collection in below code?

```
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Vector v1 = new Vector();
    Vector v2 = new Vector();
    v1 = null;
    Vector v3 = v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v1.addElement(v2);
}
```

I answered as *Yes* as object `v3` no longer getting accessed in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the code `v1 = null` the object previously referenced by variable `v1` **is candidate to be garbage collected**.

In addition no `Exception` is thrown before the end of the main so a garbage collection could happen.

Note that **is not sure that the garbage collection is invoked** and probably is not because the code will finish soon without necessity of garbage collection.

---

Here an explanation line by line of your code.

```
Vector v1 = new Vector(); // Creates a new Vector (I call it vFirst) and assign it to v1
Vector v2 = new Vector(); // Creates a new Vector (I call it vSecond) and assign it to v2
v1 = null;        // Now vFirst is not referenced by any variable so is candidate to be gc
Vector v3 = v1;   // Assign a null value to v3
v1 = v2;          // Assign to v1 the vector vSecond
v1.addElement(v2); // Add to the vSecond the element vSecond
```

As you can see after v1 = null the first Vector created can be garbage collected. It does not means that is garbage collected, but that it could be garbage collected if the GC needs memory.

Comment: the vector associated to v1 is not referenced by any line of code after v1 = null, so it is eligible to be garbage collected (is not still in use).

Comment: i read if there is no any reference to object then garbage collection will happen. But even though v1 is assigned to null, but still its bean used in the below code.

Comment: Not will, but could happen.

Comment: to me v3 will get garbage collected first is not been used at all

Comment: I edit my answer to show you each variable value and reference

Comment: Check the updated answer. It shows the whole code in terms of objects and variables.

Comment: Yes, it is better now. Thank you, for the update. (I removed my obsolete comments)

Answer (score 1):

The reference `v1` was set to `null`, therefore the object that was referred by this reference will be collected by the garbage collector. However, you cannot control the collection itself, you may ask the JVM to initiate it but it might get rejected. It all depends on the requirement of heap memory at runtime.

Comment: Can be collected if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Once you assigned `v1 = null;` the original Vector assigned to v1 is no longer accessable and will be garbage collected. v3 is null to begin with and will not be GCed

Comment: Can be collected if necessary. Is not true that it is garbage collected after v1 = null, it becomes a candidate to be garbage colllected

Comment: Davide, yes you are correct, but I assumed that this is an Interview question for a Junior level programmer, therefore on this level a candidate for GC = GC

Answer (score 1):

After you assign any object to null, the object becomes eligible for garbage collection. It doesn't necessarily imply that it will be garbage collected at that point of time.

So when v3 becomes null, it is definitely eligible for gc, but at what time it will be garbage collected is not certain.

Comment: Is not v3 the object candidate to be garbage collected. Is the vector prior referenced by v1,

Answer (score 0):

**No. v3 is just a candidate for GC.**
There is no explicit GC statement here and it cannot be =)